# C: Error in switch statement: "this is the first entry overlapping that value"

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm currently working on my LED-Strip and am using HEX-Color-Codes to work with it.
Now I wanted to make a smooth rainbow effect, by changeing the Color-Code with an switch statement.

```
 1    switch(M0_Color){
 2      case 0xff3300 ... 0xffcc00: M0_Color += 0x003300; break;
 3      case 0xffff00 ... 0x33ff00: M0_Color -= 0x330000; break;
 4      case 0x00ff00 ... 0x00ffcc: M0_Color += 0x000033; break;
 5      case 0x00ffff ... 0x0066ff: M0_Color -= 0x003300; break;
 6      case 0x0033ff: M0_Color = 0x0025ff; break; //Smoother transition
 7      case 0x0025ff ... 0x0005ff: M0_Color -= 0x000500; break;
 8      case 0x0000ff ... 0x2000ff: M0_Color += 0x0500ff; break;
 9      case 0x2500ff: M0_Color = 0x3300ff; break; //Smoother transition
10      case 0x3300ff ... 0xcc00ff: M0_Color += 0x330000; break;
11      case 0xff00ff ... 0xff0066: M0_Color -= 0x000033; break;
12      case 0xff0033: M0_Color = 0xff0025; break; //Smoother transition
13      case 0xff0025 ... 0xff0005: M0_Color -= 0x000005; break;
14      case 0xff0000 ... 0xff2000: M0_Color += 0x000500; break;
15      case 0xff2500: M0_Color = 0xff3300; break;
16    }
```

M0_Color is the variable for the color. It's value to begin is **0xff3300**.
The shown code runs in loop.
Sadly, there are only limited options for my needs, and this is the most appealing one.
Now, when I compile it, it throws two errors and a warning:
`**Warning**: "empty range specified" (here: in code lines 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)`
`**Error 1**: "duplicate (or overlapping) case value" (here: in code lines 8, 14)`
`**Error 2**: "this is the first entry overlapping that value" (here: in code lines 7, 13)`

I'd appreciate help a lot!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @paulsm4:  That is a GCC extension, and valid in GCC and several other compilers.
Poster:  The error message is perfectly clear.  What don't you understand?

Comment: @paulsm4 abelenky is right. I'm using GCC and it is valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Line 3: case 0xffff00 ... 0x33ff00:
```

You specified the higher value first.
Its the equivalent of saying

```
case 99 ... 10:    //* Specifying an empty range.  You want 10 ... 99
```

---

```
Line 8:  case 0x0000ff ... 0x2000ff
```

This range overlaps with the range above it `0x0025ff ... 0x0005ff`.
Each range must be distinct and non-overlapping.

Its the equivalent of having two ranges:  `10 ... 20` and also `15 ... 17`. They overlap.
Which `case` should the compiler select for variable `16`??

---

Finally, those error messages are perfectly clear, and explain exactly what the problem is.  Why did you have difficulty reading this?

**Reading and understanding error messages is a core skill in programming.**
*(I've never seen these errors before, but the text made it immediately obvious what the issue is)*